# Exit status for unhandled exception

Tags: c++, exception

In my CI pipeline I test the outcome of an executable when it terminates due to an unhandled exception:

```
 auto wStatus = system("myprogram");
```

but I don't know how to test wStatus for an exception. In this [documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) I can't find a clear indication of which macro should I use, so I'd need help.

Comment: There is no well defined way to interpret exit codes. All that you are guaranteed is that 0 is successful, and non-zero isn't. Anything else is determined by the OS and C++ runtime implementation

Comment: Can you test directly the code of your `program`, like `ASSERT_ANY_THROW(sut());`?

Comment: `system` is especially bad at what Alan said, because it involves an implementation-defined  action of searching and executing a copy of shell program. It may fail there already (if required shell isn't accessible) or interpretator may fail offered command

Comment: I understand. So how can I check the behavior of the executable? Is there a better alternative to system?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way: a process terminating due to an uncaught exception typically returns 134 (at least under Linux), so testing for this value:

```
REQUIRE(WEXITSTATUS(wStatus) == 134);
```

works at least for my case.

Comment: Please note that this is very system-specific. The `WEXITSTATUS` macro is POSIX (Linux, macOS) for example. Also saying that something is "typically" one way doesn't mean it's *always* that way. Or will continue to stay that way in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your warning. I'm targeting only POSIX systems so this is enough for my purpose, and anyway I can't find any better alternative.